# Media Element paused, set position and played again causes volume not coming properly, video in slow motion after some time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I need a scenario in my project  on Windows phone 7 where

1. I have to pause the Mediaelement
2. Set the position to the user defined value and play

.Eg. To go to 10th minute of media and play.

The problem I face is the voice is not coming even after the video is played, also video becomes in slow motion mode for some time.

**Sample Code** (Mediaelement will be played on Load itself)

```
private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     mediaElementVideo.Pause();
}

private void btnChangePosition_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (mediaElementVideo.CanSeek)
     {

           double changePosition = Convert.ToDouble(txtPosition.Text);
           mediaElementVideo.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(changePosition);               

           mediaElementVideo.Play();
      }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I've experienced this slow-motion behavior after using Position to reset a video, though my platform is WPF.  Not sure if these are truly related though.